# Python subprocess.Popen fails on shell command as argument

Tags: python, shell

Struggling with subprocess.Popen() - why is First and Third working as expected, while the second does not find any of multiple files or directories? Error message is:

```
>ls: Zugriff auf * nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

English translation:

```
File not found or directory: access to * not possible
```

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import subprocess

args = []
args.append ('ls')
args.append ('-al')

# First does work
cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(args)
cmd1.wait()

# Second does NOT work
args.append ('*')
cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(args)
cmd2.wait()


# Third does work
shellcmd = "ls -al *"
cmd3 = subprocess.Popen(shellcmd, shell=True )
cmd3.wait()
```

Comment: The default on Popen is shell=False, so First and Second are of this kind. They use the arguments as supplied in args. If I add shell=True, then this evaluates only to the first argument in args, and ignores the others. Hence shell command is "ls", and not "ls -al" or "ls -al *".

Comment: That's not correct - try running `subprocess.Popen(['ls'])`, you will see a different output compared to when you run `subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al'])`. What doesn't work is `subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al', '*'])`, and that is due to shell globbing associated with `*`.

Comment: (I am struggling with comments editing, forgive the mess)
I know what "*" does on the shell. What I do not understand is what happens in the execution of the Second, which should feed "ls -al *" into the shell. But it does not. Why not?

Comment: @user3815773, in the second, there *is no shell*. This is usually desired behavior -- having a shell when you don't need one is a frequent vector for bugs, and even security exploits. Of course, if you want a `*` to be expanded, then you really _do_ need a shell.

Comment: (...although arguably the better practice would be to generate the list of files in Python, perhaps using the glob module, rather than to rely on a shell to glob for you).

Comment: @Charles Duffy: "there is no shell" -- yeah, that is what I did not catch! Although I was using the Shell=True and False settings, somehow I got stuck in thinking that Python pythomagically would behave shellish. No, it doesn't. The answer is so obvious, I could bang my head now :-/.
I did solve my real problem with python code anyway, but glob will make it even easier, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default `subprocess.Popen()` doesn't have the shell interpret the commands, so the `"*"` isn't being expanded into the required list of files. Try adding `shell=True` as a final argument to the call.

Also note [the warning in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) about not trusting user input to be processed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of [shell globbing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Basically, the `*` in `ls -al *` is expanded by your shell, to match all available files.
When you run the subprocess without the `shell=True` flag, python is not able to parse the `*` on its own, and hence, the error message `ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory` is displayed.

When you run the command with `shell=True`, python actually passes the control to the shell, and hence the correct output is displayed.

As an aside, executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution, so it should be used with caution ([see warning here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)).

---

**EDIT 1**

Both shell globbing and the way `Popen` consumes `args` is causing the issue here

From [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen),

> `class subprocess.Popen`
>
> `args` should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string.
>
> If `shell is` True`, it is recommended to pass` args`as a`string` rather than as a sequence.

To understand that shell globbing and the manner in which `Popen` consumes `args` is the issue here, compare the output of the following. Note that in 2 cases, when `shell=True`, only `ls` is executed since the input passed is a `list` and not a `string`, against the recommendation

```
subprocess.Popen(['ls'])                         #works
subprocess.Popen('ls')                           #works
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al'])                  #works
subprocess.Popen(['ls -al'])                     #doesn't work raises OSError since not a single command
subprocess.Popen('ls -al')                       #doesn't work raises OSError since not a single command
subprocess.Popen(['ls -al'], shell=True)         #works since in shell mode
subprocess.Popen('ls -al', shell=True)           #works since in shell mode & string is single command
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al'], shell=True)      #output corresponds to ls only, list passed instead of string, against recommendation
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al', '*'])             #doesn't work because of shell globbing for *
subprocess.Popen(['ls -al *'])                   #doesn't work raises OSError since not a single commandfor *
subprocess.Popen('ls -al *')                     #doesn't work raises OSError since not a single commandvalid arg
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-al', '*'], shell=True) #output corresponds to ls only, list passed instead of string, against recommendation
subprocess.Popen(['ls -al *'], shell=True)       #works
subprocess.Popen('ls -al *', shell=True)         #works
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can also try using the python library **sh**

example:

```
from sh import ls

print ls("-al")
```

[link to more examples](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-sh-in-python)